# How to find in JSON array in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I want to search in an SQL column that contains a JSON

```
{
"fr":"mon titre français",
"en":"my english title",
}
```

I only want to look in the key "fr". So if I type "english" .. there should be no result.

Unfortunately I can not use the JSON_EXTRACT function, etc.

Any help ?

Comment: I have Mysql 5.5. JSON_EXTRACT exist only from 5.7. and the update would be too complicated for the moment

Comment: Just to check, you've chosen to store `JSON` as a string in MySQL 5.5?  Even though MySQL 5.5 doesn't understand `JSON`?  Which is why you stored it as a string?  And now you're faced with the problem of searching that string?  ***Hint: don't store JSON as strings if you want to search it.***  Store the JSON as a table of key-value-pairs instead.  Then your chosen storage medium *(MySQL)* has the ability to search it...

Comment: Exactly that...

Comment: @MatBailie It's a big table .. and I would add several languages

Comment: That's fine that's how relational databases work.  The new table just needs three columns: A column for the foreign key pointing to the primary_key from the current table, a column for the language key, and a column for the text value.  Then it's `SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN json_table ON main.pk = json_table.fk WHERE json_table.key = 'fr' AND json_table.value LIKE '%english%'`.  The point is to structure your data in the manner appropriate to your storage.  You chose a relational database, so store the data relationally.

Comment: Is not my solution.. Multiples columns use multilingues in multiples tables...